# Apache RewriteRule for a single static URL?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My current `.htaccess` contains the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-(.*).html$ product_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-(.*).html$ categories.php?cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

How can I add a single static rule so that `product1-p-123.html` is redirected (301) to `product2-p-456.html` without disrupting the other incoming requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^product1-p-123\.html$ /product2-p-456.html [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^.+-p-([^.]+)\.html$ product_info.php?products_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^.+-c-([^.]+)\.html$ categories.php?cPath=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```